# wildcard in linux cp

Tags: linux, shell, glob

when I use * in cp, I think it follows the same rule as regex.
so `"cp temp/* test/"` should copies everything over, however, when temp folder is empty it throws exception saying it cannot find file or directory, which indicte * cannot match "nothing".

Then I create a file test.txt under temp and do:

```
cp temp/test.txt* test/
```

It works, which indicate * indeed match "nothing".

I get confused about the behavior. Can anyone explain a little bit?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is the `*` expansion is done by your shell (`bash` probably). The pattern `temp/testfile.txt*` did match `temp/testfile.txt` (`*` matches zero or more characters), so bash passed that onto `cp`.

However, `bash` is set, by default, to pass the wildcard as-is on to the app if it doesn't match anything (there's an option called `nullglob` to turn this non-intuitive behavior off). So it passed `temp/*` literally to cp, which complained that it didn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation. I am still wondering why "cp temp/. test/" works when temp has nothing inside? Thanks

Comment: Can you double check that? When I try `cp temp/. test/` I get `cp: temp/. is a directory (not copied).` (Mac OS) or `cp: omitting directory \`temp/.'` (Linux).

Answer (score 1):

The shell does the expansion, so it's not `cp` specific.

If not match is found, there's no substitution, the original string (`temp/*`) is reserved and passed to the application. Of course `cp` cannot find a file by that name.

```
# echo nosuchfile*
nosuchfile*
```

Some clarification for "nothing":

`temp/*` means entries (files/directories/...) in `temp` directory, but there weren't any files, so it failed.

`temp/test.txt*` means entries starting with `test.txt` in the `temp` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard `globbing` is not the same as regular expressions, complete with their own rules.

Different shells have different rules ... you make want to look at [Wikipdia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) to get an overview.